# PostgreSQL - Normalization using AVG, MAX, and MIN

Tags: postgresql, max, average, normalization, min

I have a PostgreSQL table that contains 1,634 records with an "id" for each location, "disaster(n)_a" columns for the number of affected persons per disaster event, and a "disaster2_an" column for the normalized number of affected persons for the second disaster event.

```
   id  | disaster1_a | disaster2_a | disaster2_an
--------------------------------------------------
1234567|      27     |      30     |      0
5687428|      58     |      87     |      0
5874658|      88     |     458     |      0
.......
```

In order to update "disaster2_an", I have to compute for the normalized number of affected persons per location using affected persons data in both disaster events. How can I input the following function as an SQL statement that will update column "disaster2_an"?

```
disaster2_an = (disaster2_a - AVG(disaster2_a, disaster1_a))/
(MAX(disaster2_a, disaster1_a) - MIN(disaster2_a, disaster1_a))
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find an answer to my question. I just replaced MAX() and MIN() with GREATEST() and LEAST() respectively, and performed the manual method for getting the average.

```
UPDATE TABLE tbl1
    SET disaster2_an = (disaster2_a - ((disaster2_a + disaster1_a)/2)) / (GREATEST(disaster2_a, disaster1_a) - LEAST(disaster2_a, disaster1_a));
```